# Can anyone identify this plant?

Tags: species-identification, botany

We found this seemingly ornamental plant somewhere in the midwestern United States; does anyone know what it is?[image]

It's fairly low to the ground.  Thanks!

Comment: If you add some more information about this plant for example widness of leafs,  specify the somewhere part of your question and you might get your answer.

Answer (score 1):

From the general appearance, and from the opposite leaves (seen if you look carefully in the enlarged photo) I think this is *Euoynmous europaeus* ([Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euonymus_europaeus)).  Specimens I've seen can grow like a ground cover, similar to your picture, but they also get shrubby/woody.  It is not native to the US.  We'd need more details/pictures to be sure, but I'm guessing from how you worded the question these might not be available.

Comment: Euonymus europeus has green twigs that are square in cross-section. There are hardly any other species (in Europe) that have this, so it is a very distinctive feature.

Comment: It will also climb a vertical surface.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is *Vinca minor*, or periwinkle. I'm from IL and it is a common landscaped ground cover around me. It is opposite, low growing, and woody. Check out https://www.illinoiswildflowers.info/weeds/plants/periwinkle.htm to confirm, I can't give any more of a detailed answer without a more detailed picture.